# How to show CTI Adapter only on console but not on other pages

Tags: cti, visibility

I want to show my custom CTI Adapter only on Console but not on all pages (Home, Contacts & Etc.). How can I do this,

Screen where I don't want to show,
[image]

Screen where I want to show,
[image]

**Note**: I am new to Salesforce. So, assuming that this is a valid question!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Your call center users will always see the softphone in their left hand sidebar while in Classic view, as well as in their console.